# is "10 minutes" an adverb in the sentence "I am 10 minutes late"?

Tags: meaning

see this sentence "**I am 10 minutes late**"

late is an adjective in this case [Source](http://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/late)

> late1 /leɪt/ ●●● S1 W1 adjective (comparative later, superlative
>   latest)   1 AFTER EXPECTED TIME arriving, happening, or done after the
>   time that was expected, agreed, or arranged OPP early
>
> Sorry I’m late – I overslept.
>
> **ten minutes/two hours etc late** You’re half an hour late.

My question is:

is "**10 minutes**" an adverb in the sentence "**I am 10 minutes late**"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say it's a noun phrase functioning as a modifier in the adjective phrase *ten minutes late*.

It's perhaps uncommon for a noun to modify an adjective, but it's possible. A similar construction is like this:

> He is ten years old

This is usually restricted to the predicative position. For the attributive, it should be:

> He is a ten-year-old boy.

Comment: you could compare with "He arrived 10 minutes late"

Comment: @JamesK I think 'late' is an adverb here.

Answer (score 1):

> *I am [ten minutes late].*

"Ten minutes" is a noun phrase.

The bracketed expression is an adjective phrase as predicative complement, with "late" as head and the noun phrase "ten minutes" as modifier.

This contrasts with

> *We arrived [ten minutes late]*

where this time the bracketed bit is an adverb phrase with the adverb "late" as head, and "ten minutes" again as modifier.